# Stripe webook signature verification failed using express

Tags: stripe-payments

Hey stack overflow so I am using webooks with stripe. For some reason I am getting the error "Stripe webook signature verification failed". Here is my source code below. Any ideas on how I can get it working? I know it has something to do with the bodyparser. But I am not able to figure out a workaround to get the stripe webhooks working.
Error Message:

```
Webhook signature verification failed. No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing
```

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
var cors = require('cors')
const axios = require("axios");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const Stripe = require('stripe');
const stripe = Stripe('sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc'); 
const invoiceDescription = require('./constants');

const endpointSecret = "whsec_w5Qipi3Wz0fm8sSCHcJIHwWfobS0kfYe";

const { TOKEN, SERVER_URL, BOTTOKEN } = process.env;
const TELEGRAM_API = `https://api.telegram.org/bot${TOKEN}`;
const URI = `/webhook/${TOKEN}`;
const WEBHOOK_URL = SERVER_URL + URI;

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());


const init = async () => {
  const res = await axios.get(`${TELEGRAM_API}/setWebhook?url=${WEBHOOK_URL}`);
  console.log(res.data);
};

app.post('/webhook', express.raw({type: 'application/json'}), (request, response) => {
    let event = request.body;
    // Only verify the event if you have an endpoint secret defined.
    // Otherwise use the basic event deserialized with JSON.parse
    if (endpointSecret) {
      // Get the signature sent by Stripe
      console.log(request.headers)
      const signature = request.headers['stripe-signature'];
      try {
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
          request.body,
          signature,
          endpointSecret
        );
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(`⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed.`, err.message);
        return response.sendStatus(400);
      }
    }
  
    // Handle the event
    switch (event.type) {
      case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
        const paymentIntent = event.data.object;
        console.log(`PaymentIntent for ${paymentIntent.amount} was successful!`);
        // Then define and call a method to handle the successful payment intent.
        // handlePaymentIntentSucceeded(paymentIntent);
        console.log('payment intent is', paymentIntent)
        break;
      case 'payment_method.attached':
        const paymentMethod = event.data.object;
        // Then define and call a method to handle the successful attachment of a PaymentMethod.
        // handlePaymentMethodAttached(paymentMethod);
        console.log('payment method is', paymentMethod)
        break;
      default:
        // Unexpected event type
        console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}.`);
    }
  
    // Return a 200 response to acknowledge receipt of the event
    response.send();
  });

app.post(URI, async (req, res) => {
  let text = "", chatId = "", userObjectForTable = {}; 
  if(req.body.message?.chat?.id && req.body.message?.text && req.body.message?.text === "Start"){
        chatId = req.body.message.chat.id;
        text = invoiceDescription;
        const message = await axios.post(`${TELEGRAM_API}/sendMessage`, {
            chat_id: chatId,
            text: text,
            reply_markup: {
                inline_keyboard: [[{
                    text: 'Pay $65.00',
                    web_app: {url: 'https://buy.stripe.com/test_14kbKj3Gd0AGeRi7ss' }
                }]]
            }
        });
        
    }
  return res.send();
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5050, async () => {
  console.log(" app running on port", process.env.PORT || 5050);
  await init();
});
```

Comment: what is  the value of `err.message` in the `catch()` block?

Comment: I added the err.message in the description.
Webhook signature verification failed. No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing

Comment: Is the error happening on your local machine or in production? If you're running Stripe-CLI locally try to make sure that the webhook `endpointSecret` matches the one that is printed in your terminal. And if it's a hosted page make sure that it matches with the corresponding secret from your Dashboard. It's not really a good idea to hardcode the `endpointSecret` value IMO; it will change between different webhook endpoints.

Comment: I solved the issue by removing ```app.use(bodyParser.json());``` from the code and it worked. Stripe requires the raw body for processing.